# How can I write a WP_Query that is this specific?

Tags: wp-query

So I have a client that wants to select posts that display on a page very specifically. And I'm trying to edit a shortcode I've made to accommodate.

Let's say they have categories A, B, and C where each can be any category in there Wordpress. So like A could be news, blog, featured, etc. Same for B and C.

They want to be able to display posts that have (A AND B) OR (A AND C). so in boolean notation A & ( B | C ).

How can I create a WP_Query to do this? I could probably manage it with and SQL statement, but I'd really like to avoid that. I'd also like to be able to handle these relations through some short code parameters (could be 2-3 different ones), so try not to get too complicated for that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The [tax_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) attribute is what you need.

You could use it like so:

```
$query_args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'slug-of-category-a' ),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'slug-of-category-b' ),
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'slug-of-category-c' ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Or, taking advantage of the fact that the "IN" operator (that is used in tax_query when querying terms by default) already acts as an "OR" condition, you could also write:

```
$query_args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'slug-of-category-a' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'slug-of-category-b', 'slug-of-category-c' ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

This will get posts that are both in A and:

- B,
- C,
- both B and C.

Consult the docs I linked to for more options.